# Remove a worklet after use

Tags: javascript, audio-worklet

My program creates a lot of worklets from code generated at runtime. They are only used for a short amount of time. Is there a way to remove or unregister old, unused worklets to regain memory? Or is this done automatically by GC?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worklet/addModule

Comment: You should specify what is your code architecture, what is the reason you create that many worklets, can you reuse any? Can you clean up the context they're attached to? What is the reason it gets so bad. I think this is an architectural question and without more info we're not able to help.
In my case I had a single use audio context and I wasn't able to cleanup worklet tied to the audio context because of the listener collbacks passed to the worklet stored in an object to be able unsubscribe them. After I unsubscribed them I didn't clean up stored references to them that was holding memory.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like once they're loaded they'll stay there until the context it's attached to is destroyed or the browser decides it's time to dispose of the `WorkletGlobalScope`, and so I see no way to remove them after use.

But I'm no expert and have only dabbled in worklets. Perhaps someone else will have a more nuanced reading of the spec.

---

**From the specification:**

> 11.3.3 The worklet's lifetime
> **The lifetime of a Worklet has no special considerations; it is tied to the object it belongs to, such as the Window.**

> Each Document has a worklet global scopes, which is a set of WorkletGlobalScopes, initially empty.

> The lifetime of a WorkletGlobalScope is, at a minimum, tied to the Document whose worklet global scopes contain it. In particular, destroying the Document will terminate the corresponding WorkletGlobalScope and allow it to be garbage-collected.

> **Additionally, user agents may, at any time, terminate a given WorkletGlobalScope**, unless the specification defining the corresponding worklet type says otherwise. For example, they might terminate them if the worklet agent's event loop has no tasks queued, or if the user agent has no pending operations planning to make use of the worklet, or if the user agent detects abnormal operations such as infinite loops or callbacks exceeding imposed time limits.

> Finally, specifications for specific worklet types can give more specific details on when to create WorkletGlobalScopes for a given worklet type. For example, they might create them during specific processes that call upon worklet code, as in the example.

Source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/worklets.html#worklets-lifetime

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [AudioWorkletProcessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor) you can schedule your Worklet nodes for garbage collection. According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor/process):

> A node that transforms its input. A processor implementing such a node
> should return false from the process method to allow the presence of
> active input nodes and references to the node to determine whether it
> can be garbage-collected. An example of a node with this behavior is
> the [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode). As soon as there are no inputs connected and references
> retained, gain can no longer be applied to anything, so it can be
> safely garbage-collected.

I highly recommend [Audion](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/audion/cmhomipkklckpomafalojobppmmidlgl) browser extension for web audio debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the sulotion by SLbox
in the specifications its say

> destroying the Document will terminate the corresponding
> WorkletGlobalScope and allow it to be garbage-collected.

maybe it's worth trying to create the worklets from within an iframe and then destroy the iframe wen you don't need them any more.